# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout can support manual calculate height (or width)?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

My `UICollectionView` used the method in `YYKit` before, first, calculate the frame of the data and store it in the ViewModel. Update the height of the cell as a Layout delegate. This eliminates the need to calculate the height of the cell while sliding.

Now I view becomes complicated, need embedded cells of different sliding directions, so I'd like to convert `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` for layout. But `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` didn't seem to support the manual calculation height (or width) but through the way of the estimate to the layout. This is not suitable for my handwritten layout of cells. Is there any way I can dynamically change `NSCollectionLayoutSize` when I define `NSCollectionLayoutItem`?